# jQuery onclick function not working after loading in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to load a post within fancybox. The following code works well in normally loaded posts. But when I load posts in fancybox It doesn't responds. Please guide me what should I do?

Note that there are no errors in console.

```
jQuery('.selfie.like, .selfie.liked').on('click', function (e) {
});

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="selfie liked" data-id="1"></a>
```

Comment: the anchor link doesn't have the class `selfie`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that while writing here. I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're dynamically generating the anchor link.

Use event delegation as shown below.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.selfie.like, .selfie.liked', function (e) {
```

Even better if you use a static parent element to the anchor link instead of document.

```
jQuery($parentSelector).on('click','.selfie.like, .selfie.liked', function (e) {
```